# What is the significance of having two formulas for area moment of inertia?

Tags: angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

What is the significance of calculating area moment of inertia twice?
I mean calculating area moment of inertia  w.r.t axis and 
calculating same area moment of inertia w.r.t centroidal axis?
Why not area moment of inertia w.r.t axis only?

> In rectangle, they are two  area moment of inertia formulas, one with
>   axis and other one with respect to an axis collinear with the base.

Comment: Where did that quote come from? What axis does “one with axis” refer to? You can calculate a moment of inertia around *any* axis, not just one or two particular ones. In general, the moment of inertia is a *tensor*.

Comment: There are more than two.  There are an infinite number of "formulas".    There is a different moment of inertia for every possible axis, even an axis one kilometer from the object that does not go through the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the quoted statement poorly worded.

This is a guess on what they mean, but for a rectangle in the xy plane, I suspect the statement "one with the axis" means the moment of inertia of the rectangle with respect to the centroidal axis (x and y), that is, when the centroid of the rectangle is at the origin of the xy coordinate system so that the centroidal axes are the same as the x-y axes. See the figure at the left below where C indicates the location of the centroid.

Then when they say the moment of inertia "with respect to an axis collinear with the base" they probably mean the moment of inertia with respect to an axis that is collinear with the base (collinear with the x-axis). See the figure to the right below.

To say there are 2 moment of inertias for a rectangle is misleading. It only applies to the two figures below. But the rectangle can be located anywhere in the xy plane. The moment of inertia of the area is with respect to the xy axes. Since the there are an infinite number of possible locations of the rectangle, there are an infinite number of moments of inertia each unique to the specific location of the area with respect to the axes.

Generally though you start with the centroidal moments of inertia (figure at the left). Those are the values shown in the figure to the left. They are published for many basic shapes. Then if you move the area so that the centroid is no longer at the origin of the coordinate system you need to add an additional moment of inertia to the centroidal moment of inertia based on the parallel axes theorem. That is often also published for the case where the side(s) of the area contact the x and/or y axis (figure to the right). For other locations of the area with respect to the axes you need to do the calculations. In any case, the calculations are based on the parallel axis theorem. That is how the moments of inertia for the figure at the right were calculated based on the figure at the left. The theorem is given by

$$I_{x}=I_{xc}+d_{x}^{2}A$$

$$I_{y}=I_{yc}+d_{y}^{2}A$$

Where for the first equation

$I_{x}$ is the moment of inertia about the x-axis.

$I_{xc}$ is the centroidal moment of inertia about the centroidal x axis (left figure below).

$d_{x}^{2}$ 
is the distance from the x-axis to the centroidal x-axis (right figure below).

$A$ is the total area (in this case $A=bh$)

The same applies to the second equation, just substitute $y$ for $x$

Hope this helps.

[image]